# Python TypeError with sockets

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket, sys, string 

if len(sys.argv) !=4:
    print ("UsageL ./ninjabot.py <server> <port> <channel>")
    sys.exit(1)

irc = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])
chan = sys.argv[3]
sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sck.connect((irc, port))
sck.send(b'NICK ninjabot\r\n')
sck.send(b'USER ninjabot ninjabot ninjabot :ninjabot Script\r\n')
sck.send('JOIN ' + " " + chan + '\r\n')
data = ''
while True:
    data = sck.recv(1024)
    if data.find('PING') != -1:
        sck.send('PONG ' + data.split() [1] + '\r\n')
        print (data)

print (data)
```

I get this error in sck.send('JOIN ' + " " + chan + '\r\n') but when i try this:

```
sck.send(b'JOIN ' + " " + chan + '\r\n')
```

I get TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

I know there's similar posts with this same issue, but none of those seem to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `b'JOIN'` is of type `bytes` while `" "` as well as `chan` and `"\r\n"` are of type `str`.

2 corrections:

1. `chan = sys.argv[3].encode()`
2. `sck.send(b'JOIN ' + b" " + chan + b'\r\n')`

alternatively you could just:

`sck.send(b'JOIN  %s\r\n' % chan.encode())`

this would be the best style. Similar corrections will be need to be made later in your snippet as well. `socket.send` is looking for a bytes string, so ensure that all strings which you pass it are either `b""` or encoded otherwise using `encode()`